# mysql: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: permissions, mysql

Every time I try to access Mysql I get that error:

```
0 ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

nothing worked: purge, remove, clean and reinstall mysql and nothing manages to work.

does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Which solutions did you try? This always worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/22677984/7111561

Comment: it woul help if you edit the question and add the full command, which you are using to login.

Answer (score 3):

`using password: NO` tells you what is wrong. You probably have a password set for the user root --> You need to enter a **password**.

You can let `mysql` prompt for a password running:

```
mysql --password
```

or shorther:

```
mysql -p
```

If you need to connect with user root run

```
mysql --user=root -p
```

Comment: Problem solved!
The solution was uninstall MySQL (all of this) and Apache, then in the bitnami.com website I've download and installed LAMP.
Create a new admin for MySQL and then I've also changed the port number. Please check this to see if this solve your problem. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Good that you solved your problem. Please add your solution as a new answer and mark it as accepted so others can solve the same problem without the need to look through comments.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! The solution was uninstall MySQL (all of this) and Apache, then in the bitnami.com website I've download and installed LAMP. Create a new admin for MySQL and then I've also changed the port number. Please check this to see if this solve your problem. Thanks for all your help!